# Command to display how many child processes the current interpreter has

Tags: linux, unix, awk, terminal

I found that echo $$ displays current interpreter PID. So I came up with this solution:
`` ps -eo ppid | tail-n+2 | awk '{if($1==`echo $$`) print "bingo"}' | wc --lines ``

However, it doesn't work. How can i fix this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

I think you look for that

```
ps -h --ppid $$ | echo $(($(wc -l) -2))
```

-2 to remove ps and wc

Comment: Be careful answering questions like these. Some in the community feel answers should be downvoted, too. Also see [Should one downvote answers to off-topic questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194963/173448)